# readlink: illegal option -- f error in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

i have readlink: illegal option -- f error when i'm trying to use product -> archive in xcode ..

i tried to remove the "-f" tag from source="$(readlink -f "${source}")" ... and got Rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23)

i tried to add this code to podfile but its not working

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    shell_script_path = "Pods/Target Support Files/#{target.name}/#{target.name}-frameworks.sh"
    if File::exists?(shell_script_path)
      shell_script_input_lines = File.readlines(shell_script_path)
      shell_script_output_lines = shell_script_input_lines.map { |line| line.sub("source=\"$(readlink \"${source}\")\"", "source=\"$(readlink -f \"${source}\")\"") }
      File.open(shell_script_path, 'w') do |f|
        shell_script_output_lines.each do |line|
          f.write line
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

**Note:** i'm using mac m1 and the application works well on simulator

Answer (score 2):

It is that you are using an old version of macOS?

The command works ok on my system:

```
# sw_vers 
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     13.4
BuildVersion:       22F66

# which readlink
/usr/bin/readlink

# ln -s /System FakeLink 
# readlink -f FakeLink
/System
```

You could try changing your script to use the explicit path `/usr/bin/readlink` in case you are picking up some unexpected script called readlink.

Alternatively you could install the GNU readlink and use that

```
brew install coreutils
ln -s /usr/local/bin/greadlink /usr/bin/readlink
```

Comment: On my mac 11.7 (Big Sur), `/usr/bin/readlink` is the system binary, so I left that alone and added the symlink in `/usr/local/bin` (which is earlier in my `PATH`). That worked perfectly! Thanks, @Faisal!